# I erased my macbook hard disk still have recovery disk but time machine keep loading forever, what are my solutions?

Tags: macos, mac

i have an old macbook (2010) that i use from time to time, last time i tried it it was very slow, i decided to erase the main HD hoping to reinstall OSX again, but when i choose that option (connect to the internet, then login), i got the "***this item is temporarily unavailable***" Error.

I looked for it and people say that i have to use a recovery USB, but i don't have another Mac to create it, and the other solutions are using Torrented OSx.

That's why i need help from someone who knows his way around Apple product, i am only used to Windows and one or two linux distribution, but when it comes to OSx i only open it when my job requires me to do it.

Thank you

Comment: When you boot to Internet Recovery, you need to install the OS that the machine first shipped with; as at that point you have no App Store association to any purchased OSes later than that [that's the 'unavailable' message]. Other than the alternatives you mentioned, your best bet is to take it to an Apple Store. Note, for future reference, that the number of times you need to nuke & pave a Mac is approximately *nil*. It's not Windows. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228935/this-item-is-temporarily-unavailable-when-installing-yosemite & https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314

Comment: thanks for your input, so since there is no Apple Store where i live, my best bet is to use a non-legit OS ? but why can't i use the recovery partition in my mac ? it has 1.3Gb used, can't that be put to use in some way ? thanks

Comment: It might be dependant on what OS & firmware updates were already applied - that machine is right on the cusp of the introduction of Internet Recovery. Theoretically, if it gets to the Internet part, then it should be able to download & install your original OS. I'm not sure what might be preventing it. Alternatively [& assuming it still has a working DVD drive], you can get disks from Apple by snail mail.